# Image representation suitable for both WPF and Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, winforms, image-processing, drawing, system.drawing

When working with Windows forms and images, I deal with System.Drawing.Image descendats.
When I work with WPF I deal with System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource class.

Is there a UI framework independent way of referencing a memory image?
Maybe it would be a Intptr or byte array?

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on how precisely you want to retrieve and then manipulate the image. If you need to perform the latter, then you really have to go with one of those namespaces.

Comment: Well, I need to be able to display the image in both ways.
1) PictureBox in Windows forms.
2) Image control in WPF

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get them both to work with a MemoryStream pointing at a byte array (makes sense to me anyway!)

Haven't tried the WinForms way, but you can certainly do that with WPF.